# Is there a way to download all the Revision History of a Google Doc?

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to download all my Revision History as .doc documents from Google Docs (.xls from Google Sheets and PPT maybe from Slides)?

Comment: The question asks "Is there a way to download all my Revision History." It does not ask about downloading each document itself. I think the user is asking for a download of the timestamps, or similar.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, it does not appear possible to download individual revisions of Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides without going in and reverting a file to each separate revision and downloading it normally. I did some investigation into Google Apps Script and the [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk); Apps Script has no access to revision history, and the REST API does not seem offer the ability to export the contents of a revision to a file.

This does not apply to files of non-Google formats, such as Word documents, audio files, and images. As long as a version is still saved on your Drive, you can go into the "Manage versions..." dialog and download each saved version of a file.

Comment: This answer is obsolete

Comment: In correct - comment in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Now it's possible to make a copy of each version. To do that, do the following

1. Press Ctrl + Alt + Shift + H
2. Locate the desired version, then click the three dots button, then **Make a copy**. A Make a copy dialog will show up.
3. Change the options as necessary, then  click OK

Reference

- [View activity & file versions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: Incorrect - as the reference you linked to says, "Version history for Google Docs, Sheets, & Slides is different than file versions in Google Drive." OP asked about versions in Google Docs.