# Export full revision history of Google Doc

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to export the entire revision history of a Google Doc?

I am imagining the output being something like a spreadsheet that, for each edit, lists the date of the edit, the user who made the edit, and then all plaintext additions and deletions in the edit.  Possible example:

```
Date      User    Additions          Deletions
8/2/2020  Alice   I hate             You like
8/1/2020  Bob     You like vanilla.
```

(Previous questions along these lines appear to be asking how to [link to](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/47662/253423) or [download the full copy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87589/253423) of specific revisions.)